# (T)SQL Query to filter all datasets, which contain �

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode, encoding

I've just received a (MSSQL) database, which unfortunately has corrupted data in it.
In some datasets German special characters (ä/ü/ö) were substitued for a � symbol (Unicode: \uFFFD).

This is not a problem with the collation or the use of various encodings or anything (I checked that already), but rather the fault of whoever provided the orignal data, as I am pretty sure that these symbols are 'hardcoded' into the data meaning that they were "always" there and probably came into existence by a failed migration (or something similar) by the data provider.

As I can't get my hands on a proper dump without these errors, I am currently looking for the possibility to select only the datasets affected. I already tried a [...] WHERE LIKE '%\uFFFD%' statement (hoping that the DB internally decodes these symbols to the unicode code), but to no avail. [...] WHERE LIKE '%�%' works partially, as it shows all affected columns, but also all datasets containing a normal ? character (which makes this method not usable for me, as the output is far too big).

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to specifically only select the datasets containing the �?

Best regards,
daZza

Comment: What happens if you ad an "N" to your query? WHERE LIKE N'%�%' this casts the text explicitly to unicode. (as a quick fix: find a character that's not used at all, replace all normal ? character with that char, find the special � cases, process them, then after done, change special char back to ?)

Comment: Adding N gives 43260 results compared to 2155 without the N :) I'll think about that Quickfix though (I doubt it'll be quick though :P)

Comment: I think that @GarethD showed below that unicode doesn't work nicely with the like statement. Charindex shows promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results will depend on your collation settings. I was able to get it to work with a few different ones. I think the most generic is this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES (N'A�A'), (N'A?A'), (N'AAA'), (N'�A'), (N'A�'), (N'�')) t (c)
WHERE   CHARINDEX(N'�' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, C) > 0;
```

Or

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (VALUES (N'A�A'), (N'A?A'), (N'AAA'), (N'�A'), (N'A�'), (N'�')) t (c)
WHERE   C LIKE N'%�%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

When using LIKE it only seems to work with collations that use a binary sort (although I have not tried all collations!). You can get these using:

```
SELECT name, description
FROM fn_helpcollations()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work on the first look. However, I only get 29 resultsets with that query, which is too low (I also can't see some entries in there where I know that a � is present). I'll examine the CHARINDEX function further and will have another look at the original data. Could it be that there are several different unicode codes that will lead to a � being displayed?

Comment: I have just found that this has it's flaws, for example `SELECT CHARINDEX(N'�', N'A�')` returns 0. I am intrigued by this so I will carry on researching!

Comment: Makes sense. All the results I get have the � in the first character of the string. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks mate, working great now and I'm rather sure that I've got all needed datasets now. Leaves me with manual fixing of 476 rows :/